# Add TURN server to android webRtc native

Tags: android, webrtc, turn

I'm working on WebRtc native android application. Im also  compiling io.pristine lib. Im able to establish calls between two devices only if both of them are connected to the wifi. In case when one of the devices is connected to the cellular network im not able to establish call. I read any possible forum out there and its look like I need TURN server. I already run my own TURN server but idk how I can force the app to use this server. Any help is welcome. Thank you!!

Comment: could you guide me how to build io.pristine lib.

Comment: Strictly speaking, just a STUN server will be enough, but TURN will also provide a fallback if your clients are not able to establish a peer-to-peer connection. There are free public STUN servers out there, e.g. stun.l.google.com:19302.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the TURN server when creating the PeerConnection.

It will go something like this:

```
    // Set ICE servers
    List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new ArrayList<>();
    iceServers.add(new org.webrtc.PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"));
    iceServers.add(new org.webrtc.PeerConnection.IceServer("turn:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3478", "username", "credential"));

    // Create peer connection
    final PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
    PeerConnectionFactory factory = new PeerConnectionFactory(new PeerConnectionFactory.Options());
    MediaConstraints constraints = new MediaConstraints();
    PeerConnection peerConnection = factory.createPeerConnection(iceServers, constraints, new YourPeerConnectionObserver());
```

I have not run this code, but you should get the idea.

Comment: just add bracket in the end of the 2nd and 3rd line.

Comment: Hey @Mikko, my ICE servers looks like:
"stun:URL",
"turns:URL:433?transport=tcp",
"turns:URL:5349?transport=tcp"

But I see only **typ host** and **typ srflx** Ice Candidates in signaling channel.
I'm able to establish call when devices are connected to same hotspot but gets onIceConnectionChange: state=FAILED when one of them uses cellular network

Answer (score 18):

WebRTC deprecated old API to create ICE servers. ([Answer which uses old API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45494444/4247308))

To create ICE server you need to use IceServer builder pattern.

```
 PeerConnection.IceServer stun =  PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302").createIceServer();
 PeerConnection.IceServer turn =  PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("turn:numb.viagenie.ca").setUsername("webrtc@live.com").setPassword("muazkh").createIceServer();
```